# Kendo UI angular - Rotate labels of x-axis in bar chart

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-chart

I am trying to rotate labels of x-axis in smaller screens to make sure that labels do not overlap each other.

**CODE**

```
<kendo-chart *ngIf="!yearLoader" (seriesClick)="barClick($event)">
      <kendo-chart-tooltip format="{0} events"></kendo-chart-tooltip>

       <kendo-chart-category-axis>
            <kendo-chart-category-axis-item [categories]="yearChartData.months">
            </kendo-chart-category-axis-item>
       </kendo-chart-category-axis>

       <kendo-chart-series>
            <kendo-chart-series-item [spacing]="1" [data]="yearChartData.count" type="column"></kendo-chart-series-item>
       </kendo-chart-series>
</kendo-chart>
```

When i was going through the [API Documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/api/XAxisLabelsComponent/) I found `rotation` property in `kendo-chart-x-axis-item-labels`. I think that could be the solution to my problem. But, I don't know how to use that in my code. Can anybody help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can rotate labels of the **x** axis or (category-axis) by nesting a `kendo-chart-category-axis-item-labels` component within the `kendo-chart-category-axis-item` component. 
([Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/zhET9InmF5nTsOFLBG9C?p=preview))

```
<kendo-chart *ngIf="!yearLoader" (seriesClick)="barClick($event)">
    ...

    <kendo-chart-category-axis>
        <kendo-chart-category-axis-item [categories]="yearChartData.months">

            <kendo-chart-category-axis-item-labels [rotation]="45">
            </kendo-chart-category-axis-item-labels>

        </kendo-chart-category-axis-item>
    </kendo-chart-category-axis>

    ...
</kendo-chart>
```

In case you want to rotate all labels (**x** and **y** axis) use `kendo-chart-axis-defaults-labels` component and nest it within the `kendo-chart` component.

```
<kendo-chart *ngIf="!yearLoader" (seriesClick)="barClick($event)">

    <kendo-chart-axis-defaults-labels [rotation]="45">
    </kendo-chart-axis-defaults-labels>

    ...
</kendo-chart>
```

Comment: How can we use majorGridLines component

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which shows how to rotate the category axis (in this case Y) and the value axis (in this case x). For good measure I have also labeled the series and rotated those

```
  <kendo-chart>
    <kendo-chart-area background="#dad6d3"></kendo-chart-area>

    <kendo-chart-category-axis>
        <kendo-chart-category-axis-item [categories]="[2015, 2016, 2017]">
            <kendo-chart-category-axis-item-labels [rotation]="45">
            </kendo-chart-category-axis-item-labels>
        </kendo-chart-category-axis-item>
    </kendo-chart-category-axis>

    <kendo-chart-value-axis>
        <kendo-chart-value-axis-item >
            <kendo-chart-value-axis-item-labels [rotation]="45">
            </kendo-chart-value-axis-item-labels>
        </kendo-chart-value-axis-item>
    </kendo-chart-value-axis>
    
    <kendo-chart-series>
        <kendo-chart-series-item type="bar" [data]="[1, 2, 3]" color="#002c5f" [gap]="1"
            [labels]="labelOptions"></kendo-chart-series-item>
    </kendo-chart-series>
</kendo-chart>
```

Where label options are:

```
labelOptions: SeriesLabels = {
  format: '{0}',
  background: '#dad6d3',
  visible: true,
  rotation: 45,
}
```

[image]